# Sort records into buckets with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Game model that has a datetime, storing the date and time the game will be played. I'd like to put those records into an array of arrays of each date.

Example of a possible outcome array:

```
[
  [
    #<Game id: 7, datetime: "2014-03-03 05:30:00">,
    #<Game id: 12, datetime: "2014-03-03 11:30:00">,
    #<Game id: 14, datetime: "2014-03-03 12:30:00">,
    #<Game id: 17, datetime: "2014-03-03 12:45:00">
  ],
  [
    #<Game id: 1, datetime: "2014-04-06 05:30:00">,
    #<Game id: 2, datetime: "2014-04-06 11:30:00">,
    #<Game id: 4, datetime: "2014-04-06 12:30:00">,
    #<Game id: 7, datetime: "2014-04-06 12:45:00">
  ]
]
```

Here's what I'm trying so far

```
@games = Array.new
Game.all.each do |game|
  # in my model I have a function date that gets the date part of my datetime
  quit = false
  index = 0
  while !quit do
    if index < @games.length
      quit = true
      @games << [game]
    elsif @games[index].first.date == game.date
      quit = true
      @games[index] << game
    end
  end
end
```

But this seems not very ruby-like and probably not the most efficient way. Is there a better approach for this?

Comment: Do the buckets themselves have to be sorted, or do games just need to be grouped together? For example, do games for "2014-01-01" have to come before games for "2014-12-01"?

Comment: @Cupcake it would be a plus, and an even bigger one if the contents of the buckets were sorted by hours/minutes, but it's not required really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient way to do this, but it is short and readable:

```
@games = {}
Game.all.each do |game|
  @games[game.date] = [] if !@games.has_key? game.date
  @games[game.date] << game
end
@games = @games.values
```

Note that it is idiomatic Ruby to use array and hash literals `[]` and `{}` instead of their respective `Array.new` and `Hash.new` constructors.

## Update

Here's an even better way, using the `group_by` method of [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), which collections can include as a module:

```
@games = Game.all.group_by { |game| game.date }
```

Note that this will return a hash using the dates as keys, but you can easily turn this into an array by calling the `values` method on a hash.

Comment: I thought about using the dates as keys in a hash, but converting it back to an array didn't cross my mind, looks very readable compared to mine

Comment: @TMP just added something even shorter, let me know if it doesn't work.